# What causes Kinect error "Warning, a Skeleton Frame was not disposed" and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

What causes Kinect error "Warning, a Skeleton Frame was not disposed" and how do I fix it?  I am trying to use the Microsoft Kinect 1.0 SDK with C#.

Comment: Well this is just a guess, but my guess is that what causes the error is **you not disposing a skeleton frame** and you fix it by **disposing a skeleton frame**. I mean, what more do you want us to tell you? You at least have your code to go on for clues; we don't even have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dispose SkeletonFrame as displayed below

```
private void KinectAllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (!((KinectSensor)sender).SkeletonStream.IsEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            // Rest implementation
        }
```

}